# Extracting input from a UIAlertView text box Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, input, uialertview

I have gotten too frustrated from trying to find an answer to this, so I will as a question...

How can I get the raw text from a UIAlertView text box in Objective-C?

Here is my code:

```
UIButton *AppCrashButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
AppCrashButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.view.frame.size.height - 44) / 6 * 1, self.view.frame.size.width, (self.view.frame.size.height - 44) / 6);

[AppCrashButton setTitle: @"Ping" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[AppCrashButton addTarget: self action: @selector(Click) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

AppCrashButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.19 green:0.19 blue:0.19 alpha:1.0];
AppCrashButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.96 green:0.26 blue:0.21 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
AppCrashButton.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;

[self.view addSubview: AppCrashButton];
-(void) Click {
    UIAlertView *AppCrashAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"IP Ping" message: @"Please enter the IP address" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"OK", nil];
    AppCrashAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

    [AppCrashAlert show];
    [AppCrashAlert release];
}
```

It shows a custom button, that once clicked, executes the "Click" method, which pings a host.

I was wondering how I could get the text from the text input.

Thanks

Comment: FYI - `UIAlertView` was deprecated back in iOS 8. You should be using `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{ 
    NSLog(@"Entered: %@",[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]);
}
```

To get entered text in **UIAlertView** text field

Answer (score 1):

Set `UIAlertViewDelegate` delegate to Your controller

```
@interface YourViewController ()<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

After that when you create your `UIAlertView` set it's delegate to `Self` In your case here

```
UIAlertView *AppCrashAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"IP Ping" message: @"Please enter the IP address" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: @"OK", nil];
AppCrashAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
// Set delegate 
AppCrashAlert.delegate = Self;
[AppCrashAlert show];
[AppCrashAlert release];
```

Then,

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex(NSInteger)buttonIndex{ 
    NSLog(@"Text : %@",[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]); 
}
```

Comment: Where would I place this?
Also, would it be possible to alert the entered text, instead of `NSLog`ing it?